# I need to create text view like this

Tags: android, user-interface

i need help to create a text view to look like second one-> Username :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0d1Ok.png]

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want roundcorner textview with the dropdown button right ?

Comment: Good luck with that. What was the question?

Comment: @grlshu, nope, i want the second one :) but thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create custom xml file for this **layout.xml** and add to your drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="2px">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

            <corners android:radius="20dp" />

            <stroke
                android:width="0.5px"
                android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Your xml should something like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:background="@drawable/layout"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

you will get something like this

[image]

you can use image of arrow instead of ic_launcher or you can use

```
android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
android:paddingRight="15dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create /res/drawable/roundrect.xml to define our custom shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:radius="15dp" />
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="#FF000000"
        android:endColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:type= "linear" />   
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#FF000000" />
    <padding
        android:left="15dp"
        android:top="15dp"
        android:right="15dp"
        android:bottom="15dp" />
</shape>
```

Include TextView using the custom shape, with `android:background="@drawable/roundrect"`